# CSS not working into a PHP page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I can't show my CSS into PHP pages:

I have this PHP page where i wrote my CSS (stile.php):

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $url = "http://sitename.com/files/greenbutton.png";
    $colore = "#000000";
?>
a
{ background: <?echo $url;?>; 
color: <?echo $colore;?>;   }
```

This is my PHP page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pagina dei Risultati</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sitename.com/stile.php"/>
</head>


<title>Pagina dei Risultati</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sitename.com/stile.php"/>


<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die ('Impossibile connettersi');
mysql_select_db('my_palmiano', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$cognome=$_POST['cognome'];
$nome=$_POST['nome'];

if(empty($cognome) & empty($nome)) { ?>
<p align="center">Si deve inserire un Nome od un Cognome.</p>
<p align="center"><a href="http://sitename.com/cercaform.html">Torna alla pagina di Ricerca.</a></p>
<?php
exit();}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Defunti WHERE cognome LIKE '%" . $cognome .  "%' AND nome LIKE '%" . $nome .  "%' ORDER BY cognome";
$result =mysql_query($sql, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$contatore= mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<?php echo '<h2>'.'Risultati Trovati: '. $contatore.'</h2>';?>
<table border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
<tr>
    <th>Cognome</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Nascita</th>
    <th>Decesso</th>
    <th>Et&agrave</th>
    <th>Cimitero di</th>
    <th>Settore</th>
    <th>Numero</th>
    <th>Mappa</th>
    <th>Note</th>


</tr>
<?php

function calcola_eta($ggnascita,$mmnascita,$aaaanascita,$ggdecesso,$mmdecesso,$aaaadecesso){
    if ($ggnascita==0 || $mmnascita==0 || $aaaanascita==0 || $ggdecesso==0 || $mmdecesso==0 || $aaaadecesso==0){
        return 'ND';
    }
    if ($aaaanascita==$aaaadecesso ){
       return '-';}

     if ($aaaanascita<$aaaadecesso & $mmnascita < $mmdecesso){
       return (( $aaaadecesso - $aaaanascita) - 1);}

    if ($aaaanascita<$aaaadecesso & $mmnascita > $mmdecesso){
       return $aaaadecesso - $aaaanascita;
                    }
 if ($aaaanascita<$aaaadecesso & $mmnascita==$mmdecesso){
                        if ($ggnascita >= $ggdecesso) {
           return $aaaadecesso - $aaaanascita;
        } 
        if ($aaaanascita<$aaaadecesso & $mmnascita==$mmdecesso){
                        if ($ggnascita < $ggdecesso) {
                        return (( $aaaadecesso - $aaaanascita) - 1);}
          else { return 0;}
        }
    }}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
extract($row);


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $cognome . '</td>';
echo '<td>' .  $nome. '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ggnascita . '/'. $mmnascita . '/'. $aaaanascita . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ggdecesso . '/'. $mmdecesso . '/'. $aaaadecesso . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . calcola_eta($ggnascita, $mmnascita, $aaaanascita, $ggdecesso, $mmdecesso, $aaaadecesso). '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $localita . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $settore . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $numero . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<a href="http://palmiano.altervista.org/files/'. $settore . '.pdf'.'". target="_blank">' . 'visualizza'. '</a>'. '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $note . '</td>';
}
?>

</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Not minding for a moment about all those ifs and query injections (gonna correct later), why doesn't it show what i want to?
Link to page stile.php is correct, i am afraid that is not the right position for `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sitename.com/stile.php"/>` or that html is too messed up....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on to the Short Tags mistake, which is really not one (because it works in places where short tags are enabled), your CSS has a **bigger syntax mistake**:

```css
a { background: <?php echo $url;?>; color: <?php echo $colore;?>; }
```

The above code render it as:

```css
a { background: http://sitename.com/files/greenbutton.png; color: #000000; }
```

The above is a wrong value for `background`. You need to use:

```css
a { background: url('http://sitename.com/files/greenbutton.png'); color: #000000; }
```

So, for that, change your PHP code to:

```css
a { background: url('<?php echo $url;?>'); color: <?php echo $colore;?>; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've `php` **short tags** `on`, you cannot use `<?`. try this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $url = "http://sitename.com/files/greenbutton.png";
    $colore = "#000000";
?>
a
  { background: <?php=$url;?>; 
color: <?php=$colore;?>;   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PHP short_tags unless you enabled it:

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

From PHP 5.5 onwards, The tag `<?=` is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.

```
a
{ background: <?echo $url;?>; 
color: <?echo $colore;?>;   }
```

Use the full PHP tags instead:

```
a
{ background: <?php echo $url;?>; 
color: <?php echo $colore;?>;   }
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and mine ?